# Failed executing "Table to Excel" in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, excel, error-000576

Can't export polygon shapefile into Excel sheet.
When executing Table to Excel in ArcGIS shows this error:

> ERROR 000576: Script associated with this tool does not exist.
>
> Failed to execute (TableToExcel).

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: Since the error message implies that your install is corrupt, have you tried uninstall/reinstall? 10.2.2 was the terminal 10.2 release; you should reinstall that and apply the score of patches from support.esri.com